# Parity UI peers list

Tags: parity

I know I've seen a list of peers in the Parity UI before but now I don't remember the URL.  I'm going to kick myself when someone sends this link.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the health indicator:

http://127.0.0.1:8180/#/status